# Delimiter character for page title

Tags: seo, title, delimiter

I have noticed a few oddities recently with the titles of web pages in [SERPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_results_page).

However, it seems there are several main conventions:

```
Contact Page - Joe Schmoe's Awesome Site   // &#045;   Hyphen
Contact Page — Joe Schmoe's Awesome Site   // &mdash;  Em dash
Contact Page | Joe Schmoe's Awesome Site   // &#x007C; Vertical bar
Contact Page « Joe Schmoe's Awesome Site   // &laquo;  Left double angle quotes
```

Is there any reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the form you want and if Google wants to rewrite your `<title>` tag, he will do it. For your information, if your website use a specific brand, Google tends to rewrites `<title>` tag like this:

```
Your brand: your webpage description
```

Here's the information from Google on that:

> Brand your titles, but concisely. The title of your site’s home page
>   is a reasonable place to include some additional information about
>   your site—for instance, "ExampleSocialSite, a place for people to meet
>   and mingle." But displaying that text in the title of every single
>   page on your site hurts readability and will look particularly
>   repetitive if several pages from your site are returned for the same
>   query. In this case, consider including just your site name at the
>   beginning or end of each page title, separated from the rest of the
>   title with a delimiter such as a **hyphen**, **colon**, or **pipe**, like this:
>   `<title>ExampleSocialSite: Sign up for a new account.</title>`

More information on `<title>` tag [on Google support](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en).